compilation error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int32_t*' {aka 'long int*'} [-fpermissive]
i have ordered an LilyGo T5 4.7" newer gen. E-ink screen with an onboard esp32 S3
so I installed the must have libraries and the board manager.
I followed all this steps I followed al here shown steps as seen in second image
That is the tools tab in the Ardu. IDE
But I can do anything and the same errors appears all the time.
thats half of the output but points to the same error The error message on the bottom.
Here is my code
#ifndef BOARD_HAS_PSRAM
#error "Please enable PSRAM !!!"
#endif

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "epd_driver.h"
#include "font/firasans.h"
#include "esp_adc_cal.h"
#include <FS.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "image/logo.h"
#include "pins.h"

#if defined(T5_47_PLUS)
#include "pcf8563.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#endif


#if defined(T5_47_PLUS)
PCF8563_Class rtc;
#endif

int vref = 1100;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);

    char buf[128];
    /**
    * SD Card test
    * Only as a test SdCard hardware, use example reference
    * https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/SD/examples
    */
    SPI.begin(SD_SCLK, SD_MISO, SD_MOSI, SD_CS);
    // SD_MMC.setPins(SD_SCLK, SD_MOSI, SD_MISO);
    // bool rlst = SD_MMC.begin("/sdcard", true);
    bool rlst = SD.begin(SD_CS, SPI);
    if (!rlst) {
        Serial.println("SD init failed");
        snprintf(buf, 128, "➸ No detected SdCard");
    } else {
        Serial.println("SD init success");
        snprintf(buf, 128,
            "➸ Detected SdCard insert:%.2f GB",
            SD.cardSize() / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0
        );
    }

    // Correct the ADC reference voltage
    esp_adc_cal_characteristics_t adc_chars;
#if defined(T5_47)
    esp_adc_cal_value_t val_type = esp_adc_cal_characterize(
        ADC_UNIT_1,
        ADC_ATTEN_DB_11,
        ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12,
        1100,
        &adc_chars
    );
#else
    esp_adc_cal_value_t val_type = esp_adc_cal_characterize(
        ADC_UNIT_2,
        ADC_ATTEN_DB_11,
        ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12,
        1100,
        &adc_chars
    );
#endif
    if (val_type == ESP_ADC_CAL_VAL_EFUSE_VREF) {
        Serial.printf("eFuse Vref: %umV\r\n", adc_chars.vref);
        vref = adc_chars.vref;
    }

#if defined(T5_47_PLUS)
    Wire.begin(TOUCH_SDA, TOUCH_SCL);
    rtc.begin();
    rtc.setDateTime(2022, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0);
#endif

    epd_init();

    Rect_t area = {
        .x = 230,
        .y = 20,
        .width = logo_width,
        .height = logo_height,
    };

    epd_poweron();
    epd_clear();
    // epd_draw_grayscale_image(area, (uint8_t *)logo_data);
    epd_draw_image(area, (uint8_t *)logo_data, BLACK_ON_WHITE);
    epd_poweroff();


    int cursor_x = 200;
    int cursor_y = 250;

    const char *string1 = "➸ 16 color grayscale   \n";
    const char *string2 = "➸ Use with 4.7\" EPDs  \n";
    const char *string3 = "➸ High-quality font rendering ✎";
    const char *string4 = "➸ ~630ms for full frame draw \n";

    epd_poweron();

    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, buf, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);
    delay(500);
    cursor_x = 200;
    cursor_y += 50;
    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, string1, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);
    delay(500);
    cursor_x = 200;
    cursor_y += 50;
    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, string2, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);
    delay(500);
    cursor_x = 200;
    cursor_y += 50;
    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, string3, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);
    delay(500);
    cursor_x = 200;
    cursor_y += 50;
    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, string4, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);
    delay(500);

    epd_poweroff();
}

void loop()
{
    // When reading the battery voltage, POWER_EN must be turned on
    epd_poweron();
    delay(10); // Make adc measurement more accurate
    uint16_t v = analogRead(BATT_PIN);
    float battery_voltage = ((float)v / 4095.0) * 2.0 * 3.3 * (vref / 1000.0);
    String voltage = "➸ Voltage: " + String(battery_voltage) + "V";
#if defined(T5_47_PLUS)
    voltage = voltage + String(" (") + rtc.formatDateTime(PCF_TIMEFORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD_H_M_S) + String(")");
#endif
    Serial.println(voltage);

    Rect_t area = {
        .x = 200,
        .y = 460,
#if defined(T5_47_PLUS)
        .width = 700,
#else
        .width = 320,
#endif
        .height = 50,
    };

    int cursor_x = 200;
    int cursor_y = 500;
    epd_clear_area(area);
    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, (char *)voltage.c_str(), &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);


    /**
     * There are two ways to close
     * It will turn off the power of the ink screen,
     * but cannot turn off the blue LED light.
     */
    // epd_poweroff();

    /**
     * It will turn off the power of the entire
     * POWER_EN control and also turn off the blue LED light
     */
    epd_poweroff_all();

    delay(5000);
}


I have tried on another computer the same steps and it worked correctly. The problem is just the compiling that does couriosly not work on my main computer.
Can anyone help me in this case thank you all

Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part. Also when you [edit] your question, please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log into the question. And please add comments on the lines in the show code where you get the errors.

You're basically seeing compiler implementation details in action. On some compilers, "int" and "int32_t" are the same. On other computers, such as yours, they are not.

@ChristianStieber so do you know a compiler that will work on my computer?

Probably better to stick with the compiler you're supposed to use with the chip. Gain some experience and you can start playing mix-n-match, but for now you're better off going through the demos and making sure the types match. Where you get one of these errors check the variable and how it's being used. Where it is safe to do so, change the ints to int32_t. How will you tell if it's safe? You compare the values being stored in it and see if they are too big or too small to fit. Since you'll be making the size of the variable bigger (long int >=int) you should be fine.

Ive already tried to change it @user4581301 to int32_t but the same error occured and the problem is that it goes back to the library which i cant change.

All of the errors in the images, don't do that by the way, point to the ints being in the demo code and the library expecting int32. Clean up the problems you can in the demo code by replacing the affected ints with int32_ts and then see where you are at. If the library plays mix-n-match with their types (BAD LIBDARY! BAD! BAD!) yeah, there's little you can do, but lets prove that and provide error messages (as text) that let us see just how bad a library you're dealing with. At the very least, fewer error messages.

so do you know a compiler that will work on my computer?  The problem is in the code, not in the compiler.  Otherwise, not only would you have to change compilers, you'd also have to change computers.

Don't write code that depends on the size of an integer. Write portable code that can handle differently sized integers.

I fixed it myself because the problem was that I used a wrong version of the espressif esp32 boards manager. Now, with version 2.0.15 it works.
Thank you all Guys

Based on the error message, the writeln() function has a function prototype of:
writeln(const GFXfont*, const char*, int32_t*, int32_t*, uint8_t*);

In your code, the cursors are defined as:
    int cursor_x = 200;
    int cursor_y = 250;

It is not the same data type as int32_t. All you need to do is to change the data type from int to int32_t:
    int32_t cursor_x = 200;
    int32_t cursor_y = 250;

and call the function with:
    writeln((GFXfont *)&FiraSans, buf, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, nullptr);


hcheung thank you for your answer, but the Problem wasn't fixed with that solution. But I got fixed it myself because the Problem was, that I used a wrong version of the espressif esp32 boards manager now with the 2.0.15 it works. Thank you all Guys
